# Can't pass shared pointer as parameter to function definition?

Tags: c++, header, xcode8, declaration, shared-ptr

If I place a function declaration with a shared pointer as a parameter and its definition in the header, everything compiles fine, but attempting to separate them into a `.hpp` and `.cpp` file causes compilation errors like:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'std' //Solved via including <memory> & <cstdint>
Variable has incomplete type 'void' //Solved via including <memory> & <cstdint>
Use of undeclared identifier 'uint8_t' //Solved via including <memory> & <cstdint>
```

## For example:

For this main: *main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "example1.hpp" //Switch out with "example2.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> image =  0;

    foo(image);

    return 0;
}
```

### This Works:

*example1.hpp*

```
#ifndef example1_hpp
#define example1_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

    void foo(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> variable) { }

#endif /* example1_hpp */
```

### This does not work:

*example2.cpp*

```
#include "example2.hpp"

    void foo(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> variable) {  }
```

*example2.hpp*

```
#ifndef example2_hpp
#define example2_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

    void foo(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> variable);

#endif /* example2_hpp */
```

How do I separate the declaration and definition for this function into separate files successfully?

Comment: How about including all required headers in your "example" so people won't have to chase the wrong problems.

Comment: Sure, added the main, and added the other error that I have been seeing with this same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong includes. `<stdio.h>` is a C header. To use `shared_ptr` you need to include `<memory>`, to use `uint8_t` you need to include `<cstdint>`.

Comment: Ah, okay. So I need to use <iostream> instead of <stdio.h>. Strange that Xcode included automatically for a c++ file.